# Downloading csv attachment in flask (from dataframe)

Tags: python, flask

So I want to download csv as attachment but I am able to see it on browser itself and not as attachment. Here is my flask code -

```
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
    *Some Code*
    df = calc.get_data(prdrop,fr_value,sumprfit,fitids) # got dataframe

    session["df"] = df.to_csv(index=False,header=True, sep=",")
   
   
    return render_template('plot.html',url=plot_url) #renders a plot from html

@app.route("/download", methods=["POST"])
def download():
    df=session["df"]
    return df if "df" in session else ""
```

the output that I get -
[image]

I want to get this file as csv, could anyone help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer -

I should make get_response

```
def download():
    df = session["df"]
    response = make_response(df)
    cd = 'attachment; filename=mycsv.csv'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = cd
    response.mimetype = 'text/csv'
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use `send_file()` like

```
def download():
    if df in session:
        df = session["df"]
        return send_file(df,
                         attachment_filename="mycsv.csv",
                         mimetype="text/csv",
                         as_attachment=True)
    else:
        abort(404)
```

refer to this topic https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_file